# InnoDB Select For Update

Tags: mysql, pdo, innodb

If I have a simple statement as such for an InnoDB Table

```
UPDATE <table> SET locked=1, col2=<Val2> WHERE locked=0
```

Is there any need to really do SELECT FOR UPDATE?

Since InnoDB supports row level locking is there any chance of a collision even thousands of clients are executing the same script simultaneously?

Update:

Something like this would prevent locks

```
$dbh = new PDO(DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$selQuery = $dbh->prepare("SELECT <col> FROM <table> WHERE status=0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE");
$selQuery->bindColumn(<col1>, $col1);
$selQuery->execute();

$selQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

$dbh->query("UPDATE <table> SET status=1 WHERE status=0 LIMIT 1");

$dbh->commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, collisions can always occur. So using the design pattern:

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` for all the resources in a given transaction first, can prevent or shorten deadlock situations.

Suppose the following scenario:

- Process A updates table 1 & 2 in the order 1,2
- Process B updates table 1 & 2 in the order 2,1

Now process A updates, table 1, with process B updating table 2 at the same time, causing a deadlock (assumption is that the same "records/pages" are hit by this update).

If however the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` would be used in the start of the transaction, the transaction would block at the start since table 2 (or 1 whomever is faster) can not be locked (yet). The key part here is "At the start of the transaction", if you do it later, then just running the `UPDATE` is just as efficient.

Key is always to keep your transactions atomic and fast: Group the SQL logic so it can execute with the least amount of other code in between, keep lock times as short as possible.

Comment: I updated the question with code that should work. Thanks!

Comment: The transaction wouldn't fail. SELECT...FOR UDPATE creates an exclusive lock on the rows. Process B would just be blocked by process A (or whichever is faster) until the exclusive lock is released. Also just to make it clear SELECT...FOR UDPATE does a row-level lock, not a table level lock. Since a row-level lock is used theres still a possibility for a deadlock depending on the order of execution within the transactions and if there are multiple non atomic selects. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ...
COMMIT;
```

then do only that.

If you need to do this:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT stuff from table T;  -- needs FOR UPDATE
work with the stuff, and eventually 
UPDATE T ...;
COMMIT;
```

then you *do* need `FOR UPDATE` to prevent another connection from changing T.

Without `FOR UPDATE` if T were changed while you worked on the stuff, then either you would step the changes they are making.  Or they could change the stuff making your `UPDATE` incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE...WHERE` statements automatically acquire an exclusive lock on the rows being updated. You don't need to explicitly start a transaction or use `SELECT..FOR UDPATE`.

If you are selecting rows and then updating them later, then thats where `SELECT..FOR UPDATE` is used. This prevents any other client from seeing the old data of the rows before you update them.

If there are thousands of clients, each will have to acquire exclusive locks, so they could be blocked by another client who got it first before they can make their own change.